# query to firestore to check collection and document

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i am a little bit new to firebase / firestore. I am using the stripe api.

Once the user hits `start trial` on the prebuilt stripe checkout page, then it should go to firestore and create a new collection called `subscriptions` with all the users information. It seems to be doing this, however, I created a page called `successPage`, and it basically checks to make sure that it created it.

please find the code below:

```
 const successPage = props => { 

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if(user) {
      console.log("calling success page : " + user.uid)


//checking if user is paying for subscription
firestore.collection('customers').doc(user.uid).collection('subscriptions')
.where('status', 'in', ['trialing', 'active']).get()
.then(activeSubscriptions => {
  // if this is true, the user has no active subscription.
  if (activeSubscriptions.empty === true) {
    console.log(user.uid)
    firestore.collection('customers').doc(user.uid)
    .get().then(
    doc => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        firestore.collection('customers').doc(user.uid).collection('subscriptions').get().
          then(sub => {
            if (sub.docs.length > 0) {
              var activityStatus = "canceled"
              createCheckoutSession(activityStatus)
              console.log('subcollection exists');
            } else {
              alert("Your account has been created, but your payment details we're not successfully created. You will now be redirected to the checkout page")
                createCheckoutSession()
                console.log(user.uid)
                console.log("does not exist!")
            }
          });
      }
    });
  } else if (activeSubscriptions.size > 1){
    alert("you have more then one active subscription. please manage your subscriptions and cancel one of your subscriptions to access the application")
  } else {
    firestore.collection("profiledata").doc(user.uid).update({
      accountStatus: "active"
    }).then (() => {
      
      
      firestore
      .collection("roger@x.ca")
      .add({
        to: user.email,
        message: {
          
        },
      })
      .then(() => console.log("email out for delivery!"));

    props.history.push('/clients')
    
    })
    
  }
});
}

  })

  return (

     <input type="hidden"></input>
  )
}
```

it checks the subscriptions collection where status = to either trialing, or active, and then it checks everything inside subscriptions to see what is going on, but it for some reason it keeps redirecting to the stripe page (createCheckoutSession) even though the subscriptions collection has been created. is this a timing issue?

Answer (score 0):

Stripe triggers a Webhook to your server/cloud functions when a new subscription is created and after that the document is created in Firestore. This process might take some time and meanwhile your user may have been redirected to the success page. If the document has not been created yet then you won't be able to show the transaction status.

Here's a workaround that you can do:

1. While creating a Stripe Checkout session on your server, you can actually create the subscriptions document but set a field called "stripe_response" to false and also add the new subscription document ID as a query parameter in the stripe success_url. So you url maybe looks something like: `https://domain.ext/paymentSuccess?id=<that_document_id>`,
2. Now when the user is on the success page, look for that specific subscription document with the ID mentioned in the query parameter. If the "stripe_response" is still false, then maybe the webhook has not done it's job yet. Just retry the request after 5 seconds and then show the status to user. Make sure you set the `stripe_response` to true in the webhook.

To simply step 2, you can just attach a [realtime listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) on the document so when the status is updated you get the response asap and don't need to rely on polling.

Coming to the 'keeps redirecting' part, can you please specify what the exact redirect situation? Where is it redirecting and all that?

It's definitely a race condition but if you follow the steps above it should take care of it. Please let me know if you need more assistance fixing this issue.